# Array overwritten after dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that converts an array of integer vectors to an adjacency matrix , an (n+1)x(n+1) array. When in the function i have written to do this the dynamic memory allocation from setting up the int** seems to overwrite the n+1 and n+n elements of the integer vector.

```
int** makeAdjMatrix(IntVec* Vec, int length) { //allocates a new nxn array


printf(" madm  test %d \n" , Vec[1]->data[6]); 
//confirming that the intvec entered okay

int** new;
new = (int**)malloc(length+1*length+1*sizeof(int*)) 

printf(" madm  test %d \n" , Vec[1]->data[6]); 
// confirming that something happenend to the intvec

for (int i = 0; i <= length + 1; i++) {
    new[i] = (int*)malloc(length + 1*sizeof(int));
}

for (int i = 1; i <= length+1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= length+1; j++) {
        new[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

outputs normally for all elements in the vector data structure except those n+1 and above. n in this case being 5.

the above code prints

test 1

test 33

segfault 
(because there is no 33rd indices in the array which the code referrences later)

is this memory exhaustion? how am I overwriting a previously allocated array on the heap? this might be a bit vague, this is my first question go easy on me. by the way this only happens when the vector array has repeated identical input.

how bad did I mess up?

Comment: Multiplicative operators have higher precedence than additive operators.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Here are some parentheses `()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()` feel free to use them in your code to group arithmetic operators.

Comment: There is no matrix, aka 2D array. A pointer is not an array. Using a 2D array would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: 2+3*4 is 14 not 20. Remember BEDMAS or PEMDAS from primary school?

Comment: Never cast the result of malloc